# How do I maximize nvme raid0(md) performance (in linux)?

Tags: performance, xfs, raid0, nvme, mdraid

Nvme raid0 read(and write) performance is sometimes worse than the performance of one individual underlying drive.

hdparm -t /dev/md0 :

```
Timing buffered disk reads: 7054 MB in  3.00       seconds = 2350.46 MB/sec
```

hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1 :

```
Timing buffered disk reads: 7160 MB in  3.00    seconds = 2386.32 MB/sec
```

This is a datacenter hosted bare metal unit, the drives and the server are cooled properly so there is no thermal throttling due to high temps.
Drives are at about 45 C on average, as shown by  `nvme smart-log /dev/nvmeX`
Something is wrong with those low array speeds and I want to understand what. These are the full specs:

```
Epyc 7502p [2nd gen Rome 32cores/64threads]  
128 GB DDR4 32x4 3200mhz   
3x 3.8 TB samsung nvme pcie3 enteprise SSDs   
Raid0 software created with mdadm   
xfs filesystem on top of md0 created with defaults 'mkfs.xfs /dev/md0' 
debian 10 64bit with latest updates and stock kernel (no tinkering)
```

What am I doing wrong ? What am I not doing at all ? I know there are diminishing returns for any raid when it comes to speed but this is bad.

PS: off the top of your head, what raid0 read speed do you expect that system to have ?

Comment: Use a more reasonable benchmarking tool such as `fio` to test your speeds. `hdparm` is just this side of useless.

Comment: I would agree about using fio. I've never tested storage performance with hdparm. Fio examples: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Block/References/samplefiocommandslinux.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067240/how-do-i-maximize-nvme-raid0md-performance-in-linux#comment1391597_1067240) and [Stuka](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067240/how-do-i-maximize-nvme-raid0md-performance-in-linux#comment1391604_1067240) are right: use [**fio**](https://fio.readthedocs.io) for benchmarking. For example:

```sh
fio --filename=/dev/md0 --direct=1 --rw=read --bs=64k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=64 --runtime=120 --numjobs=4 --time_based --group_reporting --name=seq_read
```